# Keep a Relay ON until Switch closes

Tags: analog, relay, temperature

Im trying to fix an egg incubator, currently has a mercury switch (when the temperature reaches two points on the glass, the mercury completes the circuit, it has small holes and some metallic strips and a wires), making this an NO Switch.

Im trying to keep the resistor and the fan ON... until the temperature switch closes.

[image]

How I make a circuit that keeps the relay LOW until the switch closes?
I was thinking in a two relay solution, but will be better if they were two transistors?

[image]

Comment: You are using a change-over relay in your design. Use the other contact. Also use a dual pole relay rated for more than mains voltage, to avoid issues when someone assumes off = safe.

Comment: I think You are rigth, still I have to use two relays instead of some transistor, I will cheek it latter on the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuiWRz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As the others have said you can wire it using a normally closed contact.

Be aware that this circuit does not fail safe. If the relay contacts fall of or all the mercury drops out of the thermometer the lamp / heater will stay on. You need to consider if an additional safety thermostat is required in the lamp circuit.

Comment: Yes...!!! I ended up using something like this!!!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just about all relays are at least SPDT (single pole double throw).  The double throw part means that there is one contact that is normally open (NO) and another that is normally closed (NC).  The third contact is the common that is connected to the NC contact when the relay is not energize, and the NO contact when it is.  You can reverse the logic of the relay by flipping NO and NC.

In your case, use NC and the common as your switch in series with the fan and heater.  That means the fan and heater will run until the relay is energized, then turn off when the relay is turned on.